# How to fix call FwpmEngineOpen function caused BSOD on windows 11 22h2

Tags: windows, driver, bsod

I recently encountered the problem of calling FwpmEngineOpen method on windows 11 22h2 system causing BSOD. Not every windows 11 22h2 laptop will experience this problem. But the laptop with the problem, it reproduces the problem every time.

I tried to reinstall windows 11 21h2 on the faulty device. Failed to reproduce the BSOD problem. Then upgrade to 22H2 using the latest windows 11 ISO, which can reproduce the BSOD. So I guess the problem only exists at windows 11 22H2.

The dump is:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22621.382 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\melon\Desktop\BSOD\22017068\121222-10750-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*E:\WindowsPDB*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
OK                                             C:\Users\melon\Desktop\BSOD\06202019\win8_release
Symbol search path is: SRV*E:\WindowsPDB*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\Users\melon\Desktop\BSOD\06202019\win8_release
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 22621 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff802`61200000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff802`61e13410
Debug session time: Mon Dec 12 17:46:26.125 2022 (UTC + 8:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:16:03.795
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
..........................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
........................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP_M (1000007f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
BugCheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: fffff8025d4c4e70
Arg3: ffffe48d45e4bfb0
Arg4: fffff802614bea11

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for apegw.sys

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2217

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 3200

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2671

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 114150

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 113


FILE_IN_CAB:  121222-10750-01.dmp

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1008
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

BUGCHECK_CODE:  7f

BUGCHECK_P1: 8

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff8025d4c4e70

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffe48d45e4bfb0

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff802614bea11

STACK_OVERFLOW: Stack Limit: ffffe48d45e4c000. Use (kF) and (!stackusage) to investigate stack usage.

STACKUSAGE_FUNCTION: The function at address 0xfffff802731d1809 was blamed for the stack overflow. It is using 13888 bytes of stack.

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  SA2.0QuestUpda

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffe48d`45e4bfb0 fffff802`614c20c4     : 00000000`00000000 0b030000`00000157 00000000`00000021 00000521`00000521 : nt!KiDeferredReadySingleThread+0x41
ffffe48d`45e4c380 fffff802`614b39c2     : 000005c7`000005c7 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiExitDispatcher+0x184
ffffe48d`45e4c720 fffff802`614b3294     : ffffa989`00000000 ffffa989`2a2a9768 00000000`0000000c 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeInsertPriQueue+0x5a2
ffffe48d`45e4c7b0 fffff802`619dbb56     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`8302d370 : nt!ExQueueWorkItem+0x164
ffffe48d`45e4c810 fffff802`61957e4f     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`8302d370 00000000`00000000 : nt!ExpWnfStartKernelDispatcher+0x3e
ffffe48d`45e4c840 fffff802`61955e16     : ffff8082`8302d300 00000000`00000000 ffffe48d`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!ExpWnfNotifyNameSubscribers+0x177
ffffe48d`45e4c8b0 fffff802`61955b4e     : 00000605`00000605 00000000`00000000 000002e5`22f25990 000002e5`22eff960 : nt!ExpNtUpdateWnfStateData+0x2ba
ffffe48d`45e4c9c0 fffff802`6163d1e8     : ffff8082`84a8e000 fffff802`614d2615 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`0000001c : nt!NtUpdateWnfStateData+0x2e
ffffe48d`45e4ca10 fffff802`6162dc50     : fffff802`618a4736 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000006 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
ffffe48d`45e4cc18 fffff802`618a4736     : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000006 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
ffffe48d`45e4cc20 fffff802`619e378c     : ffff8082`94580e00 fffff802`00000000 ffff8082`00000006 00000000`00002758 : nt!PspChargeProcessWakeCounter+0x366
ffffe48d`45e4ccd0 fffff802`61a8e1fe     : 00000000`00000000 ffffa989`3f07cdf0 ffff8082`94659b50 00000000`00000000 : nt!PsChargeProcessWakeCounter+0x4c
ffffe48d`45e4cd20 fffff802`618a5ce1     : ffff8082`94659b00 ffffa989`3f330830 ffffa989`3238f940 00000000`00000000 : nt!AlpcpCompleteDispatchMessage+0x1e80fe
ffffe48d`45e4cde0 fffff802`618a5a12     : ffffa989`3238f940 ffffa989`3f07cdf0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!AlpcpDispatchNewMessage+0x291
ffffe48d`45e4ce40 fffff802`618a9480     : ffffe48d`45e4cff0 ffff8082`900ff000 ffff8082`944094f0 fffff802`614be800 : nt!AlpcpSendMessage+0x922
ffffe48d`45e4cf70 fffff802`618a6c99     : ffffa989`3f330830 00000000`00220000 ffff8082`900ff000 ffff8082`944094f0 : nt!AlpcpProcessSynchronousRequest+0x330
ffffe48d`45e4d090 fffff802`6163d1e8     : ffffa989`39273080 ffffe48d`45e4d240 ffffe48d`45e4d378 ffffe48d`45e4d168 : nt!NtAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0x1d9
ffffe48d`45e4d150 fffff802`6162dc50     : fffff802`62c5bcfe ffff8082`900ff000 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`94409480 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
ffffe48d`45e4d358 fffff802`62c5bcfe     : ffff8082`900ff000 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`94409480 ffff8082`944095f8 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
ffffe48d`45e4d360 fffff802`62c5bc12     : 00000000`00001000 ffff8082`94409480 ffffe48d`45e4d600 fffff802`62c4a0d0 : msrpc!LRPC_BASE_CCALL::DoSendReceive+0x72
ffffe48d`45e4d3d0 fffff802`62c5c5fb     : 00000000`00000000 ffffe48d`45e4d470 00000000`00000000 fffff802`62c434f0 : msrpc!LRPC_BASE_CCALL::SendReceive+0x52
ffffe48d`45e4d400 fffff802`62c42435     : ffffe48d`45e4d6c0 00000000`00000000 fffff802`62c434f0 00000000`00000000 : msrpc!NdrSendReceive+0x47
ffffe48d`45e4d430 fffff802`62c42313     : 00000000`00000000 fffff802`62c434f0 fffff802`00000007 ffffe48d`45e4d460 : msrpc!NdrpClientCall3+0xf5
ffffe48d`45e4d680 fffff802`62c6e589     : 00000000`00000000 ffffa989`39273080 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`9460d550 : msrpc!NdrClientCall3+0x93
ffffe48d`45e4da20 fffff802`62c6e3c5     : ffff8082`9392cb20 ffff8082`94610100 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : msrpc!EP_LOOKUP_DATA::LookupNextChunk+0x11d
ffffe48d`45e4daf0 fffff802`62c6e8f5     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`94610100 ffffe48d`45e4dd70 : msrpc!EP_LOOKUP_DATA::ResolveEndpoint+0x135
ffffe48d`45e4db80 fffff802`62c6e86e     : ffff8082`94610070 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`94610100 fffff802`62c6e198 : msrpc!ResolveEndpointWithEpMapper+0x6d
ffffe48d`45e4dbe0 fffff802`62c6e0d1     : ffff8082`94610070 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`94610100 fffff802`614c8d40 : msrpc!ResolveEndpointIfNecessary+0xa6
ffffe48d`45e4dc60 fffff802`62c6dfab     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`94610070 00000000`00000000 : msrpc!LRPC_BASE_BINDING_HANDLE::SubmitResolveEndpointRequest+0xcd
ffffe48d`45e4dcf0 fffff802`62c690a1     : 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`94610070 fffff802`642cd000 ffff8082`9464bd90 : msrpc!LRPC_BASE_BINDING_HANDLE::ResolveEndpoint+0xeb
ffffe48d`45e4dd70 fffff802`62c68717     : ffff8082`94610070 ffff8082`94610070 ffffe48d`45e4de39 00000000`00000000 : msrpc!LRPC_BASE_BINDING_HANDLE::DriveStateForward+0x2a1
ffffe48d`45e4ddd0 fffff802`62c6b22d     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8082`9464bd90 : msrpc!LRPC_FAST_BINDING_HANDLE::Bind+0x137
ffffe48d`45e4dea0 fffff802`642fa0f8     : 00000000`00000000 ffff36b4`d7ae09c0 00000000`00000001 ffffa989`3acce920 : msrpc!RpcBindingBind+0x2d
ffffe48d`45e4ded0 fffff802`642f9f05     : ffffe48d`45e4dff0 fffff802`00000040 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : fwpkclnt!FwppRpcBindingBind+0x1c
ffffe48d`45e4df00 fffff802`642f9e26     : ffffe48d`45e4dff0 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff fffff802`61589421 : fwpkclnt!FwppSessionCreate+0xb9
ffffe48d`45e4df70 fffff802`731d1338     : 00000000`c0000001 ffffe48d`45e517a1 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : fwpkclnt!FwpmEngineOpen0+0x56
ffffe48d`45e4dfb0 fffff802`731d11b8     : fffff802`731d3520 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffa989`2e8e28f0 : apegw!OpenEngine+0x4c [c:\devops\sa\src\features\assessmenttaking\assessmenttaking.apeg\apeg_win_dylib\apegw\firewall.c @ 616] 
ffffe48d`45e4e060 fffff802`731d1428     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffa989`383c9000 : apegw!InitWfp+0x28 [c:\devops\sa\src\features\assessmenttaking\assessmenttaking.apeg\apeg_win_dylib\apegw\firewall.c @ 313] 
ffffe48d`45e4e090 fffff802`731d1809     : 00000000`00000000 fffff802`6143e34c 00000000`00000000 ffffe48d`45e4e159 : apegw!RuleEngineStart+0x10 [c:\devops\sa\src\features\assessmenttaking\assessmenttaking.apeg\apeg_win_dylib\apegw\firewall.c @ 29] 
ffffe48d`45e4e0c0 fffff802`614cb875     : ffffa989`30172bd0 fffff802`618c2677 ffffe48d`45e517a1 00000000`00000002 : apegw!WfpIRPDispatch+0x149 [c:\devops\sa\src\features\assessmenttaking\assessmenttaking.apeg\apeg_win_dylib\apegw\firewall.c @ 180] 
ffffe48d`45e51700 fffff802`618c2c70     : ffffa989`30172bd0 ffffe48d`45e517a1 ffffa989`30172bd0 ffffa989`382210f0 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x55
ffffe48d`45e51740 fffff802`618c123c     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0022e024 ffffe48d`45e51b60 ffffa989`30172bd0 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1d0
ffffe48d`45e517f0 fffff802`618bf516     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x72c
ffffe48d`45e51a00 fffff802`6163d1e8     : 00000000`00000544 000000c8`12ffdcd8 000000c8`12ffdcd0 00000000`00000008 : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
ffffe48d`45e51a70 00007ffe`4e96eee4     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
000000c8`12ffe448 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffe`4e96eee4


FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  c:\devops\sa\src\features\assessmenttaking\assessmenttaking.apeg\apeg_win_dylib\apegw\firewall.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  c:\devops\sa\src\features\assessmenttaking\assessmenttaking.apeg\apeg_win_dylib\apegw\firewall.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  180

SYMBOL_NAME:  apegw!WfpIRPDispatch+149

MODULE_NAME: apegw

IMAGE_NAME:  apegw.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  149

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_STACK_USAGE_apegw!WfpIRPDispatch

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {286d046a-caea-634c-9c2e-ffb90d719cec}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Here is the sample code which can reproduce this issue on the laptop with the problem. By the way, if I comment the code in file firewall.c which locate in test_driver from line 176 to line 184, issue disappear.

sample code: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoZBPdtrfQp1hAMIkW0MgVcq7sVJ?e=AWklwy

Comment: In your handler for IOCTL_WFP_FETCH_LOG you're blowing up the stack with ST_WFP_LOGFORM. Either allocate in on the heap or rework it to be smaller.

Comment: Year, I notice that. So I modify it, and the issue disappear. But I did not call IOCTL_WFP_FETCH_LOG in the program, this makes me very confused that why bsod happened at here.  And only some version of windows 11 have this issue.